Should a language have both null and undefined values?
Javascript for example has both null and undefined values. They are nearly equivalent: both are falsy values that denote absence of data, the only difference is apparently whether or not it was "intentional". Uninitialized variables contain undefined but the developer could explicitly set them to null to denote that it was intentional and not a mistake.
Is this useful? Is this a good idea for a dynamic language? Or is it enough to have just null?

FWIW, I suspect that null was added to Javascript to satisfy the bosses who wanted it to be more like Java. The language lets programmers write x - y without caring whether y is a number or a numeric string, so it seems implausible the design intention was for programmers to care about something much subtler.

And FWIW, SQL has null, which sometimes means missing and not applicable, and other times means missing though applicable.  The former is meant to suggest that the type of a row is different, as happens when you have a table of employees with a column referring to their manager, since the CEO doesn't have a manager, then her manager is null, there meaning missing an not applicable.  Whereas the latter usage of null means merely we didn't collect that information (like phone number or address).  So, there's two usages of null yet there's no way of dynamically distinguishing between the them.

In addition, NULL is also used in SQL to mean an empty/nothing value, i.e. the value is not missing, and it would be valid for a non-empty value to exist there, but the value happens to be empty/nothing. For example, a "products" table with a column holding an optional foreign key into the "discount codes" table could have NULL meaning that this product happens to have no discount code.

@kaya3 Products and CEO seem to be similar case, except perhaps for the distinction of whether that column can have other values for this row. Maybe one way to separate those 2 NULL uses is to ask "how many?". Then for product discount and CEO's manager it's 0. But for phone or address is "I don't know".

See three-valued logics and four-valued logics.

I feel like the general rule is: if you see it in JavaScript and not elsewhere it was probably a bad idea. JS is a very poorly designed language.

A language should have neither. Use option types instead.

It can be useful for verification. VHDL goes a step further, their std_logic type has nine possible values, these often come in handy during debugging.

It would be good if it was consistent, but you explicitly assign undefined and it's not the same as an actual missing field.

Another approach beyond option types is some form of polymorphism, so that the relevant column/field for missing and not applicable items is itself absent (then no need for null in that column).

What about NaN is that another type of null?

SAS is designed to work with survey data and has multiple null values, so you can have one that means 'not filled in' and one that means 'illegible', etc.

According to the zero-one-infinity principle, no. Why commit just two billion-dollar mistakes in your language?

Classic Visual Basic had Null (database semantics), Nothing (null reference) and Empty (unassigned variable) and the runtime also had a "missing" special value for an unassigned formal parameter. It was confusing! But also sometimes useful. See my 2003 article if you want more details: https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/30/a-whole-lot-of-nothing/


both are falsy values that denote absence of data, the only difference is apparently whether or not it was "intentional"

The main problem with Javascript having both null and undefined is that they are used inconsistently, even in the standard library.  There is no absolute authority which says what each should be used to mean or indicate, and so different programmers imbue them with different meanings. Library code mostly has to treat them the same way, because there is no agreed standard for how they should be treated differently.
Perhaps to you, null means an "intentionally" missing value and undefined means an "unintentionally" missing value, but this isn't universal. The ECMAScript specification doesn't seem to have anything to say on the subject. MDN advises that null means "the intentional absence of any object value" but doesn't give the opposite advice for undefined. And as an example from the standard library, canvas.getContext('2d') returns null when the same canvas is already in use in a 3D context, something very unlikely to be done intentionally.
Worse, "intentionally missing" isn't as clear a distinction as you might think. For example, function parameters take the value undefined when no argument is provided, but an argument could be missing either intentionally or unintentionally. Likewise, map.get(missingKey) returns undefined, but the key could be absent either intentionally or unintentionally. (Meanwhile, localStorage.getItem returns null instead in the same case.) The intent where a value is produced may also be different than where it is used.
As a result, if you come across some variable which might hold an object, or null, or undefined, you will have to read the comments (hopefully there are some!) to figure out what the author intended by that. Perhaps the author didn't even intend to treat them differently, just there is a mix of undefined and null because those values came from different places and there was no need to unify them.
If instead there was a language-wide authoritative standard which said undefined means one thing and null means another, then this would be less of a problem, although there would still be code which doesn't follow the standard. That said, if you can think of a clear difference between what these two values should mean in your language, then you can probably think of better names for these values which would communicate those meanings.

Nitpick: canvas and localStorage are not part of the ECMAScript standard library. They are part of the HTML5 Web API, which is a completely different library, defined by a completely different standards organization, and is language-independent, i.e., not related to ECMAScript. So, there should not be any expectation that its ECMAScript bindings are idiomatic – Language bindings of language-independent API specifications generally aren't.

In particular, WebIDL, the language Web APIs are specified in, doesn't have a null type like ECMAScript, instead, it has nullable types T?. And while it has a type called undefined, WebIDL's  undefined is different from ECMAScript's undefined – WebIDL's used to be called void and is closer to Java's void than ECMAScript's undefined.

I think reading "intentional absence of any object value" as giving a contrast of "intentional" against undefined's description focuses on the wrong place; the key contrast is in "object", because null is an object value (has the object type, i.e. typeof null == 'object'), and undefined` is not (type undefined), which is somewhat significant in JavaScript's type system, so they are not interchangeable. This reading is in the question but could be rebutted here.

I think the null being “intentional” is less of an authoritative prescription than an observation of an emergent property of the design. A more precise statement would be that the undefined value is sometimes implicitly conjured when referring to something that fails to have a value entirely (such as non-existent object properties, unassigned variable bindings or absent keys in a Map), but null is never conjured in this way, and can only result when code is specifically written to that effect.

@JörgWMittag WHATWG APIs are hardly language-independent at all. They assume ECMAScript semantics in their definitions. They are JS-centric in much the same way as JVM is Java-centric and .NET is C♯-centric, and arguably to an even larger extent.

It is useful but not necessary and there are better alternatives.
Dynamically typed languages have the limitations that they can only discover concrete types of values. That means they cannot differentiate between levels of a value being undefined: a function taking a value: Option[T] = None cannot find out whether it received the default None or was passed one if T is itself some Option[T'].
This can be practically fixed by having more than one "not defined" value: A function taking a value: T = undef can trivially separate the case of default undef and passed in None.
Of course this only shifts the problem: While for many practical problems eliminating half the collisions is enough, collisions still occur. A function that has to operate on both default and passed in undef/None still cannot separate the cases.
A more thorough approach is to allow/encourage defining new "not defined" values/types for each use. For example, Python has the idiom of using a hidden, bare object() as needed.
# placeholder with unique identity
_no_default = object()

def find(predicate, values, default = _no_default):
   ...

Of course a language can provide tools and syntactic sugar to make this simpler.

In Ruby, default arguments are re-evaluated on each call, unlike Python's which are evaluated only once. So, a very similar pattern in Ruby is something like def find(predicate, values, default = (no_argument_passed = true; nil)). This will assign true to no_argument_passed IFF the default argument was evaluated, i.e., no argument was passed. If an argument is passed, no_argument_passed will be defined but not initialized, which means it will evaluate to nil, which is falsy. The Rubinius Ruby implementation had an internal, unspeakable undefined value for this use case.

In Rubinius, large parts of the core library were written in Ruby, but there are many methods in the core library which have semantics that are hard to express in Ruby. (A vestige of there being no specification and only a single implementation with most of the core library written in C with privileged access to the interpreter internals.) Being able to reliably determine the number of arguments passed is one of those hard to express semantics – effectively, many methods in the Ruby core library are overloaded on arity, which is not easily accessible from Ruby itself.

It's a little different than your

difference is apparently whether or not it was "intentional"

characterization, but R has a somewhat unique implementation with NULL and NA that addresses the same fundamental issue, where NULL represents an undefined value (internally, it points to a singleton global constant and is effectively treated as its own unique type) and NA represents a scalar value that is missing or unknown. A key thing is that NA values in R are type-aware (there's an internal NA constant for each type) and can be used in place of scalar values; they will even propagate through calculations. They can be thought of as a convenient wrapper around sentinel values and have well-defined rules distinct from NULL.
For reference, I believe the pandas library in Python has implemented something similar to R's NA (specifically through pandas.NA), and Julia (a much newer language) has missing as an NA analog. I don't know the details of these, so they might be interesting to look into as well.
Here's an example where I create a vector and try replacing values with NA and NULL:
vec = 1:5
vec
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

vec[2] = NA
vec
# [1]  1 NA  3  4  5

vec[4] = NULL
# Error in vec[4] = NULL : replacement has length zero
vec
# [1]  1 NA  3  4  5

The NULL assignment failed because I couldn't put something of zero length into a slot that required something of length 1.
If I try to create a vector with each, NA is retained, NULL is not:
c(1, NA, 3, NA, 5)
# [1]  1 NA  3 NA  5

c(1, NULL, 3, NULL, 5)
# [1] 1 3 5

And with math, NA values are preserved:
vec + 3
# [1]  4 NA  6  7  8

They help distinguish between optional unknown inputs and required unknown inputs in defining functions:
f = function(a = NA, b) { # equivalent to b = NULL as a default
  print(a)
  print(b)
}

f(a = 1)
# Error in print(b) : argument "b" is missing, with no default

f(b = 2)
# [1] NA
# [1] 2

Thinking about return values from functions, getting NA as a result indicates that there is a value; you just don't know what it is:
mean(vec)
# [1] NA

Whereas NULL indicates that nothing was returned from a function.
Now, that doesn't mean the design is perfect and all the rules are intuitive, far from it. Keep in mind, though, that R is a statistical language that relies heavily on vector and data table structures in applications where missing data can be common. The types of language design decisions that best improve the daily experience of a statistician using R vs. a web developer using JavaScript are going to be different.

I like that you mention R but I don't think its rules are consistent. As you show, assigning NULL to an element of a vector raises an error but creating a vector with c(1, NULL) doesn't. Why should that be? Also list(a=NULL) is different to l=list(a=1);l[[1]]=NULL or l=list(a=1);l$a=NULL, which doesn't make sense to me. Additionally, TRUE || NULL is TRUE while FALSE || NULL raises an error (admittedly because the RHS isn't evaluated in the first case rather than directly related to NULL - but it can cause surprising errors). And let's not even get into NaN.

The typical NULL usuage would be to make an empty vector or list and then to add elements to it. If you have a NULL vector and concatenate the number 3 to it, afterwards you have a vector of length 1 with the value 3. If instead you start with a vector NA, it will have length 1 and if you concatenate the number 3 to it, you will get a vector of length 2 containing (NA, 3).

@SamR Yeah, by no means do I think all of the R's rules make sense, at least not without more context of the reasoning behind those decisions. Part of the reason I mentioned Julia is because it might be interesting to see what it does differently from R as a newer language with the benefit of hindsight. I just haven't done much with Julia to be able to say.

@SamR A single element of a vector has length 1 so you can't put NULL there. c(..) on the other hand, concatenates its arguments and each argument can already have a length, so you can put numbers in there (length 1), vectors (length >=1) or NULL (length 0).

@quarague I think it's less about how it works and more about the why. It is reasonable to ask why the creators did that instead of treating it as an error. I suspect there are pros and cons to both ways. Likewise, instead of making assigning NULL to an existing vector element an error, they could have made it remove the element instead. Maybe there are good reasons from a user standpoint for all their decisions. But I also wouldn't be surprised if some decisions were based on implementation complexity, performance, or weird interactions with other things.

@quarague I suppose there's a logic to that but it's not the only way to do concatenation. In Python [1] + [None] is not the same as [1] + [] and intuitively that makes more sense to me. In any case it still doesn't seem consistent that l=list(NULL); l[[1]]=NULL creates a list of length one and then a list of length zero.

If the language doesn't provide this, programmers who need the distinction will end up implementing it themselves, perhaps using a clumsy structure like:
struct optional_or_null<T> {
  enum {
    UNDEFINED;
    NULL;
    DEFINED;
  } flag;
  T value;
}

Putting it in the language definition means we don't get myriad, incompatible definitions like this. This then paves the way for common programming conventions so we use the built-in null vs. undefined distinction consistently.
Of course, conventions don't force this consistency, but it's still better than everyone rolling their own designs.
We may also be able to do better in language designs. JavaScript allows you to assign undefined explicitly. If undefined is supposed to represent "not initialized", this seems to contradict it -- you can't initialize something to "not initialized". Ideally we should only be able to test whether a variable equals undefined, not pass it around as a first-class value.
On the other hand, second-class values raise their own problems. If you have a function that compares values, it's frustrating if you can't pass undefined as the value to compare with.

This seems to assume that two undefined values is exactly what all those downstream users will need, which is the very assumption questioned here.

I propose to look at how missing values are dealt with in other fields, specifically, databases.
The SQL standard provides NULL value. But for specific use cases, Ralph Kimball recommends avoiding using it and providing meaningful not-NULL values instead.
Following this recommendation, in my recent project I had 8 different replacements for NULL values, each signaling the reason why the data are missing: all, explicit empty, not applicable, invalid, multiple, not yet created etc. Separate values primarily and greatly simplify debugging. But some business logic could also rely on them.
So, there are more criteria to use null than just 'whether or not it was "intentional"'. Two values aren't enough to cover all use cases. And that's why I think having both null and undefined is a useless complication.
I recommend this:

Add just null for 'not intentional'. Or forbid uninitialized variables
For 'intentional' cases, consider adding a separate type/class/construction, with the ability to provide and get additional info: the reason why it's empty and maybe other

Note that #2 may be not the part of the language core, but provided by a library.

"Note that #2 may be not the part of the language core, but provided by a library." - unless the library as such is defined to be part of the language core.?

@ghellquist, I don't quite understand your question. By a library, I meant something like optional-js. But it should be maintained by the language creator, not a side developer

And if you imply that a language may not have a concept of library (package, plugin, etc.) at all, IMO, it can't be used for complex programs, and this whole question is not relevant

the point is that how to implement language features may differ. This means that specific library functions may be part of language core definitions and hence not optional.

If you find this feature essential, you should probably add discriminated unions instead, as that covers what you really need to do and more. You want to have a type that is either an X, an unknown X and an inapplicable X (and probably more).
A problem you may encounter is that your users will also need their data store to support this, if it doesn’t then it will be of limited value (for nulls).
